# Constrain size and aspect ratio of Image Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a list tile that will display an image in the leading widget. This image comes from the net and I don't know the exact size.

How can I make sure the image widget doesn't become too big if it receives an image with non square proportions?

Comment: Hey! As a reminder, you should post some code to show us that you tried to solve the problem and failed to do so. Only then can we help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fit` property in the `Image` Widget. which takes a `BoxFit` value and you can specify it as `BoxFit.cover`, That way no matter what the size of the image, it will cover the entire height and width of the `Image` Widget. You can specify the height and width of the image as fixed in this case like 60x60.

More About **Image** **Widget** and its properties [Here.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html)